# Stepper motor runs extremely slow

Tags: c, stm32, keil, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

I wanted to try some C code from Github for controlling a stepper motor.
https://github.com/gavwhela/STM32F4-Projects
connected the motor drive to the STM32F407 board and the motor drive LEDs starting blinking in sequence. Since I'm able to see the sequence, it means it's working; however, it's very slow.

I tried all three modes in the code (High torque, micro stepping, and low power). However, the motor keep rotating extremely slow, almost not noticeable.
I've also noticed that the motor is becoming warm when turned on; I'm not sure if this is normal.
I need to run this motor at its max speed.
I'm using ukeil IDE, and the motor is 28BYJ-48.

Comment: warm stepper motors are normal. They exert power keeping the spindle in a location. IE, they're on all the time.  I doubt we're going to have any insight into a 6 year old github project through. How fast do you think the LEDs should be blinking?

Comment: well I think I shouldn't be able to see it blinking, I think I should be seeing it on due to fast blinking

Comment: If it was intented to be too fast to see it, what would be the point of adding a LED?

Comment: Did you verify what speed is to be expected with `ARR=300;`? Did you try different values?

Comment: Google "stm32 set tim2 frequency" to get ahead.

Comment: @Gerhardh I tried to increase the value (foolishly) which didn't work, however I just tried smaller values and it started to rotate as it should, and the LED is continuously on as expected. Thanks!